# Selecting value in hash

Tags: ruby

I got this JSON output from Ripe.

```
[
  {"name"=>"organisation", "value"=>"ORG-MI1-RIPE"},
  {"name"=>"org-name", "value"=>"Mira Internetsolutions ApS"},
  {"name"=>"org-type", "value"=>"LIR"},
  {"name"=>"address", "value"=>"Mira Internetsolutions ApS Nybovej 19 DK-7500 Holstebro Denmark"},
  {"name"=>"phone", "value"=>"+45 9610 1510"},
  {"name"=>"fax-no", "value"=>"+45 9610 1511"},
  {"name"=>"admin-c", "value"=>"MIA3-RIPE", "referenced-type"=>"person-role", "link"=>{"xlink:type"=>"locator", "xlink:href"=>"http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/person-role/MIA3-RIPE"}},
  {"name"=>"admin-c", "value"=>"MIA3-RIPE", "referenced-type"=>"person-role", "link"=>{"xlink:type"=>"locator", "xlink:href"=>"http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/person-role/MIA3-RIPE"}},
  {"name"=>"mnt-ref", "value"=>"rh-mira", "referenced-type"=>"mntner", "link"=>{"xlink:type"=>"locator", "xlink:href"=>"http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/mntner/rh-mira"}},
  {"name"=>"mnt-ref", "value"=>"RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT", "referenced-type"=>"mntner", "link"=>{"xlink:type"=>"locator", "xlink:href"=>"http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/mntner/RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT"}},
  {"name"=>"mnt-by", "value"=>"RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT", "referenced-type"=>"mntner", "link"=>{"xlink:type"=>"locator", "xlink:href"=>"http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/mntner/RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT"}},
  {"name"=>"source", "value"=>"RIPE", "comment"=>"Filtered"}
]
```

I can't rely on it being in the same order every time. I have about 200.000 IP's to check. How can I search for:

```
"name" => "address"
```

and then get:

```
"value" => "Mira Internetsolutions ApS Nybovej 19 DK-7500 Holstebro Denmark"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Array](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Array) and [Enumerable](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable) methods. In this case, [find](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable#find-instance_method):

```
data.find { |datum| datum['name'] == 'address' }
# > {"name"=>"address", "value"=>"Mira Internetsolutions ApS Nybovej 19 DK-7500 Holstebro Denmark"}
```

Comment: You actually want `['value']` after that.